# A parameter named "_="+somenumber using AJAX of Jquery? Why?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I want to know what's the use of these number? Every time I use `$.ajax()` with a "GET" method, then the Jquery will automatically add a parameter named "_" like this?

```
http://localhost/checkLogin?_=1503822124889
```

Comment: this looks like a unix timestamp and you might have some interceptor in your ajax workflow

Comment: This technique is also used to avoid caching.

Comment: Usually for caching, when you set cache:false in Ajax settings